# A better approach for the following (better time complexity) than the recursion I have used

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

There are n balls each with a particular weight and cost. The balls have to be removed such that the cost of the balls removed is maximum. An additional condition is that the sum of weights of the last k balls should be <= the weight of the the remaining balls multiplied by another constant Q (k is a constant: given). The balls can only be removed from the ends. How can the cost be maximised. I can solve this question using a recursive algorithm. But I would like to know how to reduce the complexity O(n) using queues.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

long int Q, val[100000], wt[100000],k,n;

long int steal(long int l,long int r,long int cut)
{
    long int i,sum,steal1, steal2 ,X, Y = 0;
    for(i = r; i > r - k; i--)
        Y = Y + wt[i];
    sum = 0;
    for(i = l; i <= r; i++)
        sum = sum + wt[i];
    X = sum - Y;
    if(X * Q < Y)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        steal1 = steal(l, r-1, r);
        steal2 = steal(l+1, r, l);
        if(steal1 == 0 && steal2 != 0)
            return steal2 ;
        else if(steal1 != 0 && steal2 == 0)
            return steal1 ;
        else if(steal1 == 0 && steal2 == 0)
        {
            if(r-l+1 == n)
                return 0;
            else 
                return val[cut];
        }
        else
        {
            if(steal1+val[r] > steal2+val[l])
                return steal1+val[r];
            else 
                return steal2+val[l];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    long int i;
    scanf("%ld %ld %ld", &n, &k, &Q);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%ld", &wt[i]);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%ld", &val[i]);
    printf("%ld\n", steal(0, n - 1,n));
    return 0;
}
```

Test Case :
5 2 1 (n, k and q respectively)
5 4 6 3 2 (weights of the n balls)
3 2 4 2 2 (Value of each ball)

Answer : 5

Comment: If you want help on _improving_ code, try [codereview.se]

Comment: C or C++ ? (you tagged both). You'd better make a choice, as there is no language as "C/C++". But looks more like C to me, so maybe remove the C++ tag.

Comment: @Arc676 Emphazize on ***working code*** please, if recommending SE Code Review.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a request for code-review.

Comment: @Olaf no I want to know if a better algorithm exists than the recursion which I have used

Comment: He is looking for a better complexity, this is in my opinion valid stackoverflow material

Comment: In first place you can lower complexity to O(N^2) by using [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: @SamSegers For that, I'll need a huge 3D array, hence not a viable option.

Comment: I did not criticise qour question. It is just imo not good here. It is also too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Things to be fixed:

1. You have some arrays declared with 100000 elements, regardless of the actual value of `n`, which should be their size instead. If 100000 < `n`, then the arrays are too small and you will have problems due to index out of bounds. If `n` < 100000, then you waste a lot of memory. Instead of initializing arrays with 100000 element, initialize them with `n` elements. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) for further info.
2. You could use [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) while reading the input, to sort the elements by weight, value, or some formula, so you will be able to differentiate balls by weight, or value, or some formula which suits your needs better.
3. With recursion you are using the stack. You could use a custom [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) for that purpose.
4. If you want to queue the balls, then the queue can be the one created at 2.
5. If you want the very best solution, then you will need to implement [Divide et Impera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) for your purpose.